# Faster list manipulation

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large numpy array whNumPylements I individually want to multiply with other indexes and then sum up. My current code is relatively slow, does anyone have an idea how I could make it faster:

```
result = 0
n = 1
int_array = np.array((3,16,3,29,36))
for i in int_array:
    result += int(i) * n
    n *= 10
```

Comment: 0 * 10 is always 0!!!!

Comment: ups sorry updated it to n= 1

Comment: are you sure about `n*=10`? The `n` is going to become gigantic very quickly. Except serious problems with lost precision.

Comment: yes thats intentional, to shift every number by one place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In every iteration `10 * prev(10 * ...)`, So you can use `10 ^ [0, 1, 2, ...] = [1, 10, 100, ...]` with numpy.array & [`numpy.power`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.power.html). Then you need `[1*int_arr[0], 10*int_arr[1], ...]`. At the end, you need [`numpy.sum()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html).

```
res = (np.power(10, np.arange(int_array.shape[0])) * int_array).sum()

print(res)
```

Output:

```
389463
```

Comment: thats a quick thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think i have understood that you want to progressively multiply each number of the array by `n`, and `n` is going to be multiplied by 10 each loop. Is that is what you want to do, I think there is nothing much to do. The only thing is that you dont need to convert `i` to an int, as `i` is already one